# Question closed as duplicate not showing the duplicate question or even it being closed

Tags: bug, duplicate-questions

Not entirely sure what's going on here, but the following question has been closed as a duplicate: [Simple vanilla JavaScript event listener not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60075015/simple-vanilla-js-event-listener-not-working)

It does show the linked question in the sidebar, but no where else?

Update: There was a pending edit on the question. After the edit had gone through, the issue on the question itself is fixed.
[image: Screenshot of question]

Comment: _"Everybody has a testing environment. Some are lucky enough to also have a production environment."_

Comment: @CodeCaster My guess is that it has something to do with the edit that was pending? Now that the edit has gone through, it's fixed

Comment: That's it, see also https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/393633/tried-to-close-question-got-duplicate-in-title-but-not-actually-closed

Comment: @CodeCaster Ah, I'll close this one as a duplicate of that one. No need to have multiple reports open. Or wait, this report was earlier, hmm. Ah well

Comment: Your automatic "Does this answer your question?" comment pinged me. :D

Comment: @CodeCaster Lols.. Here's another one, ghehe. Anyway, thanks man :D