# Tried to close question, got "duplicate" in title but not actually closed

Tags: bug, status-completed, closed-questions, dupehammer, post-notice

The question [Bash loop thru file takes only first line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60074853/bash-loop-thru-file-takes-only-first-line) displays with the suffix "[duplicate]" in the title for me, but I did not actually manage to close the question.

[Dharman reports a similar experience.](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/48511758#48511758)

I have a gold badge in [bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bash) and have closed many questions as duplicates in the past; but now all of a sudden it looks like the operation glitched somehow.

Comment: The post is closed, but the notice banner is not displayed as long as there is a suggested edit pending.

Comment: @Dharman _"the notice banner is not displayed as long as there is a suggested edit pending"_ - nice, how'd you come to that conclusion?

Comment: @CodeCaster I am a programmer. Solving bugs is in my job description.

Comment: The edit is no longer pending and the close reason box is now displayed.

Comment: @Dharman causing them is in mine, we should team up and become rich!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a bug, which seems to have started happening today. The post notice is not displayed as long as there is a pending suggested edit. Once the edit gets approved or rejected the notice appears.

It looks like it is only a visual bug. The question is closed and you can't answer or close it again. You can even cast reopen votes. It is only the banner that is missing.

Comment: I assume its as of yesterday, perhaps as a side effect of this being implemented https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/339700/new-post-notices-are-live-network-wide/340472#340472

Answer (score 5):

As pointed out by Nick A, this was indeed a regression bug that came about when I converted the Pending Edit notice to use the Post Notice model instead of injecting its text inline. Thanks for reporting, the issue should be fixed now.